# Free vector icons

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, icons, toolbar

Are there any free vector icons (as in, suitable for use in an open source project using WPF)  for basic desktop program toolbar buttons like Back, Forward, Print, Save etc.?

Comment: Similar Question having a lot of sources - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/315819/source-for-xaml-toolbar-icons

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the SVG versions of [Tango](http://tango.freedesktop.org/Tango_Icon_Library) (PD) and [Nuvola](http://www.icon-king.com/projects/nuvola) (LGPL).

Answer (score 3):

I'm using the free Icons from Grafile. They are completely XAML.

http://www.grafile.com/presentation/Vista_Toolbar_library.html

Comment: Hmm, I get a dead link for that one, on attempted download....looks nice though.

Comment: Just tried it out and it worked for me. Just click the Download Sample link or use directly this Link: http://www.grafile.com/download/vista_toolbar_xaml.zip

Comment: Dead links for me too; both the page link and the zip link.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout these: http://icocentre.com/

One free collection. All icons availble in XAML, SVG, and PNG formats. This service allows to change icon colors to align them with your color theme.