# Where can i get Icons for my context menu menu item in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, icons, menuitem

Can anyone suggest me some good sources for downloading icons which i can add in my WPF forms context menu.I am looking for icons for "Cut" ,"Copy","Paste","Delete"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Propose to try [iconfinder](http://www.iconfinder.com/).

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using some third party tools, check if they have a library of images(syncfusion have that). Otherwise you can look for icons here (I always get what I need here) -

> XAML icons for Silverlight and WPF:
>   http://xamlbase.com/

http://www.iconaholic.com/index.html

http://www.iconspedia.com/

http://www.recursosvisualbasic.com.ar/htm/ocx-componentes-activex-dll/107-paquete-de-iconos-en-formato-bmp-gif-png.htm

Answer (score 1):

Some duplicate posts, which have much more information related to this -

XAML -

> Source for xaml toolbar icons? -
>   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315819/source-for-xaml-toolbar-icons
>
> Free vector icons -
>   [Free vector icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667235/free-vector-icons)

PNG etc. -

> Where can one find free software icons
>   / images? -
>   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139944/where-can-one-find-free-software-icons-images
>
> Free set of forms, icons, styles, etc
>   for web-based admin interfaces -
>   [Free set of forms, icons, styles, etc for web-based admin interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145565/free-set-of-forms-icons-styles-etc-for-web-based-admin-interfaces)